# How can I group an array of samples by the threshold price with samples name as sub array key?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, iteration

I have an array of product samples that I am trying to group by the threshold price, with the rest of the samples to be accessed by the samples array.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
[
  {
    "threshold": 20.00,
    "samples": [
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "threshold": 100.00,
    "samples": [
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

EDIT: And the fetchSamples data I am working with (before it is inputted into foreach as the input): e.g. `var_dump($sortedProducts)`

This code is working ok as intended.

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
     "sampleid"=> "1234" (length=4)
     "productid"=> "11111" (length=5)
     "threshold"=> "20.00" (length=5)
     "stock"=> "345" (length=4)
     "product"=> "Beauty sample 1" (length=16)
        
  2 => 
    array (size=9)
     "sampleid"=> "5678" (length=4)
     "productid"=> "22222" (length=5)
     "threshold"=> "20.00" (length=5)
     "stock"=> "2449" (length=4)
     "product"=> "Beauty sample 2" (length=16)
        
   3 =>
    array (size=9)
     "sampleid"=> "999" (length=4)
     "productid"=> "33333" (length=5)
     "threshold"=> "100.00" (length=6)
     "stock"=> "345" (length=4)
     "product"=> "Beauty sample 3" (length=16)
```

And my PHP code where the where that grouping happens. This is the attempt where the $sortedProducts is taken in the loop and  $sortedProducts is used to output this modified data:

```
  $sortedProducts = array();

        foreach($fetchSamples as $samplekey => $sample)
        {

           $sortedProducts[$sample["threshold"]][] = $sample;
        }
```

However the closest I have gotten to this solution when I dump $sortedProducts after the foreach loop:(e.g. `dump($sortedProducts)` );

```
Main issue is trying to get the results grouped by the threshold and trying to having it as the fields with an sub array of samples containing threshold identified by same key. 

[
    {
        "20.00": [
            {
                "sampleid": "1234",
                "productid": "111111",
                "threshold": "20.00",
                "stock": "345",
                "product": "Beauty sample 1",
            },
           
            {
                "sampleid": "5678",
                "productid": "222222",
                "threshold": "20.00",
                "stocklevel": "2449",
                "product": "Beauty sample 2",
            }
        ],
        "100.00": [
            {
                "sampleid": "9999",
                "productid": "33333",
                "threshold": "100.00",
                "stock": "345",
                "product": "Beauty sample 3",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: _"However the closest I have gotten to this solution:"_ - what you have shown after this, is supposed to be your _input_ data, so what `$fetchSamples` contains, yes? If so, then you are looping over the wrong level to begin with. You have an array with one object, and you want to loop over the properties of the object. But instead, you are looping over the array.

Comment: You need to edit your question and paste the output of `var_export($fetchSamples);`

Comment: I have edited my question so it not only has the output of ```var_export($fetchSamples);```, but is also a bit more clear.

Comment: Where's the code where that grouping happens? Is that simple loop the complete attempt? What does already work, what not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that you looking for ?

[Example code](https://onlinephp.io/c/0d8de)

```
$arrs = array(
'1' => array(
     "sampleid"=> "1234",
     "productid"=> "11111",
     "threshold"=> "20.00",
     "stock"=> "345",
     "product"=> "Beauty sample 1"
    ),
'2' => array(
    "sampleid"=> "5678",
    "productid"=> "22222",
    "threshold"=> "20.00",
    "stock"=> "2449",
    "product"=> "Beauty sample 2"
    ),
'3' => array(
    "sampleid"=> "999",
    "productid"=> "33333",
    "threshold"=> "100.00",
    "stock"=> "345",
    "product"=> "Beauty sample 3"
    )
);

$data = array();

foreach($arrs as $key => $value){
    $data[$value['threshold']]['threshold'] = $value['threshold'];
        $data[$value['threshold']]['samples'][] = array(
                'productid' => $value['productid'],
                'stock'     => $value['stock']
            );
}

print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[20.00] => Array
    (
        [threshold] => 20.00
        [samples] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [productid] => 11111
                        [stock] => 345
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [productid] => 22222
                        [stock] => 2449
                    )

            )

    )

[100.00] => Array
    (
        [threshold] => 100.00
        [samples] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [productid] => 33333
                        [stock] => 345
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I was after.  Also wanted to remove the numeric array keys, which I implemented myself via returning the $data value with array_values: so e.g.```array_values($data);``` So I see I had to append the threshold value instead of whole array value and append the samples sub array values using another key group. :)

Comment: @dcrean you was almost there :)